# Compare two dates in VueJs

Tags: date, vuejs2, compare

I am trying to compare two dates in a VueJs application.
I need to show whether the selected date is higher / not than today's date.

I applied separate functionalities to get today's date and the selected date. Both return the date in dd-mm-yyyy format.

When I compare those two dates using,

```
if (dateEntered < currentDate) {

    }
```

it is not working.
How do I compare the two dates?

Comment: I found this with a google search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: what is the type of date ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `moment` come in handy. Like below

```html
var date1 = moment(dateEntered).format("dd-mm-yyyy")
var date2 = moment(currentDate).format("dd-mm-yyyy")
if(date1 >  date2){
    //Do your thing
} else {

}
```

You need to install `moment` and import it `import moment from "moment"`

Comment: The right format should be uppercase: "DD-MM-YYYY"

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on previous answer, if you're using a date library (`moment` or `date-fns` for example), you can use their [utility function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) :

`moment('2010-10-20').isBefore('2010-10-21'); // true`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone using the **dayjs** than you can use this function. It will return true or false.
https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/is-same-or-before

```
export function isSameBefore(fromDate, toDate) {
  return dayjs(fromDate).isSameOrBefore(toDate)
}
```